# Adding sticky class when scrolled past element

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an element inside my vue component I want to apply a fixed class when the user scrolls past it, however it's not taking effect, and I can see the sticky console.log is firing every scroll instead of only when the element is passed. I also want to remove the class when the element is not passed by.

Here is my component with jquery code.

```
<template>
<div id="sticky" style="width:35%; height:85vh; padding:0px 0px; margin:0px 0px 0px auto; background-color:rgb(10,10,10); display:flex; flex-direction:column; position:relative; border:5px solid #9d0000; overflow:hidden; outline:2px solid red;">
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<!--SCRIPTS-->
<script>
import $ from 'jquery';
export default {
name: 'CARTmodal2',


mounted() {
    console.log(this.$options.name+' component successfully mounted');

    let sticky = $('#sticky'),
    stickyTop = sticky.offset().top,
    scrolled = false,
    $window = $(window);

    /* Bind the scroll Event */
    $window.on('scroll', function(e) {
        scrolled = true;
    });

    let timeout = setInterval(function() {
        /* If the page was scrolled, handle the scroll */
        if (scrolled) {
            scrolled = false;
            if ($window.scrollTop() >= stickyTop) {
                sticky.addClass('fixed');
                console.log("sticky");
            }
            else {
            sticky.removeClass('fixed');
            }
        }
    }, 200);


},



};
</script>
<style scoped>
.fixed{position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; border:1px slid black;}
</style>
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are adding classes externally to Vue ecosystem, Vue replaces the class contain in a update and this ignore your external changes, use a internal conditional and the `:class="{'fixedClass':isScrolled}"` param to add or remove it.

Maybe this example of how create an header fixed could help you in the part of handle the scroll event.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sticky_header.asp